# Save plots from diagonalNetwork

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, networkd3

Is there a way to not use the GUI to save images created with the `diagonalNetwork` library?

I have tried `+ ggsave` but that didn't work.

For example

```
diagonalNetwork(sample_image, fontSize = 30) + ggsave("directory")
```

But I received the following error

> Error in diagonalNetwork(sample_image, fontSize = 30  : 
>       non-numeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `diagonalNetwork` library but is it just that your syntax is slightly off?

Would this work:

```
library(tidyverse)

diagonalNetwork(sample_image, fontSize = 30) %>% ggsave("directory")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about `diagonalNetwork` from the [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) package...

```
library(networkD3)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")

network_plot <- diagonalNetwork(as.radialNetwork(hc))
saveNetwork(network_plot, file = "network_plot.html")
```

or if you want to do it in a `dplyr` chain...

```
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")

diagonalNetwork(as.radialNetwork(hc)) %>% 
  saveNetwork(file = "network_plot.html")
```